# About javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

A strange problems about javascript  prototype :

```
(function(w){
  if(!w)
    return;

  var TestJS = function(){
  };

  TestJS.prototype = {

    data:{},
    initData:function(){
      this.data={
        val_name_1 : 1,
        val_name_2 : 2,
        val_name_3 : "hello-3"
      };
      console.log(this.data);
      return this;
    },

    TestChildJS:{
      initChild:function(){
        console.log(TestJS);
        console.log(TestJS.data);
        console.log(new TestJS().data.val_name_1);
        console.log(TestJS.data.val_name_1);
      }
    }
  };
  window.TestJS =  new TestJS();
})(window);
```

why 'TestChildJS' can not get 'val_name_1'?

```
TestJS.initData();
console.log(TestJS.TestChildJS.initChild());
```

[console pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpzWm.png)

so I have to write my code like that:

```
(function(w){
  if(!w)
    return;

  var TestJS = function(){
  };
  TestJS.prototype = {

    data:{},

    initData:function(){
      this.data={
        val_name_1 : 1,
        val_name_2 : 2,
        val_name_3 : "hello-3"
      };
      console.log(this.data);
      this.TestChildJS.initParentData(this);
      return this;
    },

    TestChildJS:{
      parentData:{},

      initParentData:function(parent){
        this.parentData = parent.data;
        return this;
      },

      initChild:function(){
        console.log(this.parentData);
      }
    }
  };

  window.TestJS =  new TestJS();
})(window);
```

How to use the first way can get the content of the second way?

Comment: because the `TestJS` in `initChild` is **not** `window.TestJS` ... and `data` in `new TestJS().data` will be, by definition of your code, an empty object until `initData` is run

Comment: BTW, `(function (window){...}(window))` is pointless. If you want unequivocal access to the global object, use *this*, as in: `(function(window){...}(this))` noting that in non–browser hosts, *window* will be the global object and not a Window object.

Comment: @JaromandaX   thx , in the first code initChild () method , I can get the data like that: console.log(window.TestJS.data.val_name_1);

Comment: @JaromandaX I thought it was important to point out *why* TestJS and window.TestJS are not the same in this particular case. It's because `var TestJS` inside the closure creates a new local binding.

Comment: That's why you posted an answer and i merely made a comment

Answer (score 0):

> why 'TestChildJS' can not get 'val_name_1'?

when:

```
TestJS.initData();
```

is run, it adds a *data* property to the *TestJS* object (the one assigned by `window.TestJS =  new TestJS()`). That property isn't inherited by any other object.

When:

```
console.log(new TestJS().data.val_name_1);
```

is run, the object returned by `new TestJS()` has not had it's *initData* method called yet, so it doesn't have a *data* property and it doesn't inherit it from the constructor (because the property is directly on the constructor itself, not its prototype).

Note also that assigning a new object to *this.data* creates a property directly on the instance, so adding to *this.data* is modifying the instance's *data* object, not the one on the constructor's prototype.

The patterns in your code (especially the second one) seem unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: I don't think the OP's problem was.with that particular line. It seems to have been added just for debugging purposes. The immediately following line was checking `TestJS.data` and was still returning undefined. I think this is a scoping issue.

Comment: Perhaps, I can't see the image posted by the OP. The question is poorly framed as it doesn't say what is expected in the first place. Perhaps time to close.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the scope of the IIFE. A variable declared inside a closure shadows any outer variable with the same name. Since after the IIFE executes you no longer have access to its scope, TempJS inside it will always be a function constructor -- not an instantiated object.

Consider this example:

```
var i; 
var func = (function(){
   i = 1; 
   return function() { 
        console.log(i) 
   }; 
})(); 

func(i); // 1

i = 2; 
func(i); // 2
```

If I re-declare the `i` variable inside the closure, look what happens:

```
var i = 1; 
var func = (function(){
   var i = 1; 
   return function() { 
        console.log(i) 
   }; 
})(); 

func(i); // 1

i = 2; 
func(i); // 1
```

So one solution to your problem would be to declare `TestJS` once before the IIFE.

```
var TestJS;

(function(w){
  if(!w)
    return;

  TestJS = function(){
  };

// ...

    TestChildJS:{
      initChild:function(){
        console.log(TestJS.data.val_name_1);
      }
// ...

    window.TestJS =  new TestJS();
})(window);

TestJS.initData(); 
console.log(TestJS.TestChildJS.initChild()); // 1
```

Notice that I removed `console.log(new TestJS().data.val_name_1);`. `TestJS` is no longer a constructor function, so that line will throw.

Another solution is to assign the empty function expression to `window.TestJS` inside the closure, instead of `var TestJS`. Doing so will not create a local `TestJS` name and will therefore prevent the ambiguity.

Comment: Note that *window* is passed in to *w* so might as well use that (as pointless as it is). Either `TestJS = function...` should be `w.TestJS = function...` or `window.TestJS = new TestJS()` should be `TestJS = new TestJS()`. i.e. either use the *w* alias for *window* everywhere or not at all.